# uploads to place

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets

I am handling file upload and want to put the files in one folder.

After going through some sites I came to know.

Solution 1: we can put the files in our webapps/appname/images
Drawback: if we redeploy war then it will be deleted.

Solution 1: Using absolute path.
Drawback: I have to hardcore path at some place.

So I thought of putting the file at Tomcat/uploads/images folder.

Is this the correct place to put our uploads?
How will I get the path of Tomcat directory stored.

I can go to context root place and find absolute path of it and then one step back will take me to webapps dir.
is this correct way to do so.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Yes`,You can put there. `Tomcat home directory` or `Catalina directory` is stored at the `Java System Property environment`. If the Java web application is deployed into Tomcat web server, we can get the Tomcat directory with the following command

```
System.getProperty("catalina.base");
```

Comment: Thanks...i checked my environment variable and found that I have not set anything such. by going through some website I came to know catalina.sh/catalina.bat does it. just want to confirm is that is the case?

Comment: After you deploy  on tomcat then only you get  that path .Otherwise it will give null.You asked about tomcat root path right to save the files

Comment: Thanks Suresh, one question I am able to put the file in Tomcat/images/uploads now. problem is now accessing it. how to access the image from that directory as <img src="relative path"> takes relative path and absolute path is not working.